# Get the last record first, then the rest in the ascending order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `roles` that I would want to retrieve the data in a special order.

The table has `id` and `description` fields.

I would like to get the last row value description FIRST, then get the rest of the description data in the ascending order.

I mean retrieve the last id first, then the rest in the normal ascending order.

The table is referenced by another table hence can not be rearranged to achieve this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option sorts using a subquery to find the last description:

```
SELECT id, description
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourTable) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    id;
```

If you are using MySQL 8 or later, then we can try avoiding the subquery by using `MAX` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT id, description
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    IF(id = MAX(id) OVER (), 0, 1),
    id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please write down.

```
   SELECT id, description
    FROM @tbl
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN id= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @tbl) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this.

```
SELECT id, description
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN id= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @tbl) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Example:---

```
Declare @tbl Table(
id INT ,
description   Varchar(50),
description22   Varchar(50),
DeptId INT
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'g1','g2',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(2,'g2','g3',NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(3,'g3','g1',NULL)


SELECT id, description
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @tbl) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you are downvoting an answer.

Comment: Please see the added example in answer.